# How to add active class on the span next of the input (type=" radio "and checked ="checked ")?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to add an  active class to the span next to the input radio which have status  checked , we are having 15 same div in apage.

**given is the code :**

```
<div id="age_restric1" class="singleselect">
    <label for="age_restriction" class="required">Age Restriction <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="ms-parent">
      <button class="ms-choice" type="button" style="width: 58px;"><span class=""> 18+</span>
      <div class=""></div>
      </button>
      <div class="ms-drop top" style="width: 58px; display: none;">
         <ul style="max-height: 250px;">
            <li>
               <label>
                  <input type="radio" value="" name="selectItem">
                  <span>None</span></label>
            </li>
            <li>
               <label>
                  <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="18+" name="selectItem">
                  <span>18+</span></label>
            </li>
            <li>
               <label>
                  <input type="radio" value="19+" name="selectItem">
                  <span>19+</span></label>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="singleselect">
    <label class="required" for="appropriate_atti">Appropriate Attire <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="ms-parent">
      <button class="ms-choice" type="button" style="width: 130px;"><span class=""> Casual</span>
      <div></div>
      </button>
      <div class="ms-drop bottom" style="width: 130px;">
         <ul style="max-height: 250px;">
            <li>
               <label>
                  <input type="radio" value="" name="selectItem">
                  <span>--Select Attire--</span></label>
            </li>
            <li>
               <label>
                  <input type="radio" value="339" name="selectItem">
                  <span>Business Casual</span></label>
            </li>
            <li>
               <label>
                  <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="338" name="selectItem">
                  <span>Casual</span></label>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript :

```
 setTimeout(customdrop, 200);
         function customdrop(){
                    $(".singleselect :checked").each(function(){
                    $(this).next('span').addClass('active');
                    });


             }
```

Comment: can you please create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: "Normal" people use CSS: `.singleselect :checked~span { /* active styles here */ }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('.singleselect input[type="radio"]:checked+span')
```

To access the `<span>`s next to checked radios.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)** in jquery

```
$(".singleselect [type=radio]:checked").each(function () {
     $(this).next('span').addClass('active');
 });

 function customdrop() {
     $(".active").removeClass('active');
     $(this).next('span').addClass('active');
 }
 $(".singleselect [type=radio]").on("change", customdrop);
```

### [UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HuKab/19/)

Comment: Hi, Bala Thank you for your reply 
It does not full fill my requirement, i all ready have tried this , its works for the last one

Comment: @Jainandansinghbaghel what do u need ?

Comment: i want for every checked in a page , as i have described that there are 15 things in a page,so its apply only for the last one

Comment: @Jainandansinghbaghel i updated post now ..i think it may be help you ..but i cant understand clearly requirement.. see demo

Answer (score 0):

$("#.ms-drop bottom li").each(function(){

```
if($('input').is(':checked')) { 
    $(this).closest('li').find('span').addClass('active');
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 jQuery("input[name=selectItem]").each(function(){
            if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')){
            jQuery(this).next('span').addClass('active');
            }
        })
```

Comment: Some commentary on how this differs from OP's code, and why this works where OP's code does not, would be useful, both for OP and those who come later.

Answer (score 0):

$(".ms-drop bottom li").each(function(){

```
if($('input[type=radio]').is(':checked')) { 
    $(this).closest('li').find('span').addClass('active');
}
```

});